# Convert back string from JSON.stringify to array

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is it possible convert string from JSON.stringify back to Array?

Comment: you can use parseJSON if you are using jquery

Answer (score 22):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is your friend and answer :)

```
//examples:
JSON.parse('{}'); // {}
JSON.parse('true'); // true
JSON.parse('"foo"'); // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null'); // null
```

[MDN JSON.Parse details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Beware of browser compatibility issues, as noted on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON.

Comment: dude it's talking about ff 3.5, that's like history :) all browsers today support JSON...

Comment: Yep, I know, but IE8- still haunts the web...

Comment: it's supported in IE8..http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: Well... It all dependes on the target audience, but I think it's always better to use a polyfill like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in case the browser does not support the native APIs.